# Highlight not more than 2 checkboxes(li) with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am really new to jQuery. I wanted to make checkboxes appear as buttons so they can be used as such. I have done all thatl the buttons (li) gets highlighted on click as I have used toggleClass function which changes the background. I just want to limit it to maximum two buttons to be highlighted (class added) at any given time. At the moment it is working on all the li items (check boxes) at any given time.

You can also visit the live demo here:
http://www.babaraliseehar.com/onepage/index.php.
Click on compare button to see the modal.

```js
$("#answers-type1 li").click(function() {
     // $(this).css("background-color","#27B249");
     $( this ).toggleClass( "place" );
});
```

```css
.place {    background-color: #27B249 !important;  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="answers-type1" class="myclass"  style="list-style: none;padding-right: 10px;padding-left: 10px;">
    <li class="module" style="background: #668693;" value="Listol"><input name="listol"  type="checkbox" value="Listol" class="number" style="display: none;"><span>Listol</span></li>
    <li class="module" style="background: #668693;" value="Synaptal"><input name="synaptal"  type="checkbox" value="Synaptal" class="number" style="display: none;"><span>Synaptal</span></li>
    <li class="module" style="background: #668693;" value="Synaptal"><input name="focus_formula"  type="checkbox" value="Focus Formula" class="number" style="display: none;"><span>Focus Formula</span></li>
    <li class="module" style="background: #668693;" value="Bright Spark"><input name="bright_spark"  type="checkbox" class="number" value="Bright Spark" style="display: none;"><span>Bright Spark</span></li>
    <li class="module" style="background: #668693;" value="Triple Complex"><input name="triple_complex"  type="checkbox" class="number" value="Triple Complex" style="display: none;"><span>Triple Complex</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check of total place class count.

```
($("#answers-type1 li.place").length < 2)
```

```js
$("#answers-type1 li").click(function() {
     // $(this).css("background-color","#27B249");
    if ($("#answers-type1 li.place").length < 2 || $(this).hasClass('place')) {
         $( this ).toggleClass( "place" );
    }
});
```

```css
.place {    background-color: #27B249 !important;  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="answers-type1" class="myclass"  style="list-style: none;padding-right: 10px;padding-left: 10px;">
    <li class="module" style="background: #668693;" value="Listol"><input name="listol"  type="checkbox" value="Listol" class="number" style="display: none;"><span>Listol</span></li>
    <li class="module" style="background: #668693;" value="Synaptal"><input name="synaptal"  type="checkbox" value="Synaptal" class="number" style="display: none;"><span>Synaptal</span></li>
    <li class="module" style="background: #668693;" value="Synaptal"><input name="focus_formula"  type="checkbox" value="Focus Formula" class="number" style="display: none;"><span>Focus Formula</span></li>
    <li class="module" style="background: #668693;" value="Bright Spark"><input name="bright_spark"  type="checkbox" class="number" value="Bright Spark" style="display: none;"><span>Bright Spark</span></li>
    <li class="module" style="background: #668693;" value="Triple Complex"><input name="triple_complex"  type="checkbox" class="number" value="Triple Complex" style="display: none;"><span>Triple Complex</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you Volkan, but your code does not remove the class when I click the highlighted button again.

Comment: Please check again. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

```
var limit = 2;
 $("#answers-type1 li").click(function() {
   if($(this).siblings('.place').length >= limit) {
   return;
}
   $( this ).toggleClass( "place" );
});
```

Try something like this - setting the limit in a variable so you can change it and then checking how many items in the list have the class already. If it is 2 do nothing otherwise add the class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hasClass` and `addClass` & `removeClass`

```js
var checkCounter = 1;
$("#answers-type1 li").click(function() {
 // checking if the element has the class
  if (!$(this).hasClass("place")) {
    // checking the value of the counter
    if (checkCounter <= 2) {
      $(this).addClass("place");
      // after adding class increase the counter
      checkCounter = checkCounter + 1;
    }
  } else {
    // if already have class then remove it
    $(this).removeClass("place");
    // decrease counter
    checkCounter = checkCounter - 1;
  };




});
```

```css
.place {
  background-color: #27B249 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="answers-type1" class="myclass" style="list-style: none;padding-right: 10px;padding-left: 10px;">
  <li class="module" style="background: #668693;" value="Listol"><input name="listol" type="checkbox" value="Listol" class="number" style="display: none;"><span>Listol</span></li>
  <li class="module" style="background: #668693;" value="Synaptal"><input name="synaptal" type="checkbox" value="Synaptal" class="number" style="display: none;"><span>Synaptal</span></li>
  <li class="module" style="background: #668693;" value="Synaptal"><input name="focus_formula" type="checkbox" value="Focus Formula" class="number" style="display: none;"><span>Focus Formula</span></li>
  <li class="module" style="background: #668693;" value="Bright Spark"><input name="bright_spark" type="checkbox" class="number" value="Bright Spark" style="display: none;"><span>Bright Spark</span></li>
  <li class="module" style="background: #668693;" value="Triple Complex"><input name="triple_complex" type="checkbox" class="number" value="Triple Complex" style="display: none;"><span>Triple Complex</span></li>
</ul>
```